# Why can't I connect to xmlrpc.launchpad.net?

Tags: networking, launchpad, bazaar

I tried to check out the source code of **opencog**(cogbuntu) using bazaar using the commands they had mentioned in their wiki.

This is the code entered in the terminal

```
bzr branch -r40 lp:cogbuntu cogbuntu-11.10
```

This is the error I got

```
ERROR: Connection error: while sending CONNECT xmlrpc.launchpad.net:443: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

Can anyone explain how to make this thing work?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem until recently.

First of all, if you are behind a proxy, you need to set `https_proxy`, NOT "http_proxy", because Launchpad uses https. If you have `curl` or `wget`, you can confirm your proxy setting is working by running something like this:

```
curl https://code.launchpad.net/
```

Secondly, there has been a long-standing bug about ssl certificates, which would prevent you from checking out projects through a proxy, even if correctly configured. This has been fixed in version 2.5.1. If you have an earlier version, even 2.5, you have to upgrade to 2.5.1 (the current stable).

Answer (score 0):

Do you perhaps have a HTTP proxy? `echo $http_proxy` should tell you.

You may want to try:

```
 bzr branch -r40 https://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/cogbuntu cogbuntu-11.10
```

which will avoid the XMLRPC step.

Comment: I check the HTTP proxy, there was one.
I remove the proxy using following command

export http_proxy=""

I get the same error even after doing this: 

bzr branch -r40 https://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/cogbuntu cogbuntu-11.10

When I try to branch using the above Bazaar command I get the following error:

ERROR: Connection error: curl connection error (couldn't connect to host)
on https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%2Bbranch/cogbuntu/.bzr/smart

Comment: Does this error has something to do with curl download manager.
I've tried it after doing both uninstalling & re-installing curl. But I get the same error

How do I work this thing around?